# SQL How to list Columns in a Table as a Cursor Statement

Tags: sql-server, tableview

below is the only method by which i have been able to pull the table names out of our database, replacing the top 1 for 2, 3, 4..... 499, 500.

The problem is that there isn't direct access to the database, the use of a third party program (for law firms) has to access the data and this gives limited scope as to what can be done, thus the usual methods of bringing back data won't generally work.  Data seems to be returned using cursors based on the errors output when using "for xml auto".

```
select(
(select min(name) from 
(select top 1 name from sys.Tables order by name desc)
as ax) + ', ' + 
(select min(name) from 
(select top 2 name from sys.Tables order by name desc)
as ax)  + ', ' + 

)
```

now i wish to repeat this procedure to return the second, third, fourth column_name within a table. THe below could works to retrive the first column_name

```
SELECT TOP 1 COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns where TABLE_NAME = <table name>
```

but my attempts to repeat the first procedure fails; top 2, top 3 etc returned the same column_name.

Help would be great.

thanks.

Comment: I assume this is SQL Server from `sys.tables`? You can use `XML PATH` to concatenate comma delimited strings there are probably over 100 questions on SO that cover how to do this. Please provide example desired results for the table columns.

Comment: Hi @Martin – problems we’ve got here is that I’m self teaching, and not too sure of all the terminology/appropriate solutions, second, I’m using a proprietary database, which gives me no access to the sql other than via a field builder. The second issue is that the field builder route wont let a script which will return multiple values, hence the method above. As for what type of SQL, i think its MSSQL, but again cant confirm this.

As for the printout of the column names, just a list such as below will do find – it is only for my own reference
Address Line 1
Address Line 2
Town
Postcode

Comment: Did you try the embedded `for xml auto` query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to embed the `for xml auto` query in another select statement

```
select (select table_name, column_name, ordinal_position, data_type
        from information_schema.columns
        where table_name = 'T'
        order by 1,3
        for xml auto)
```

Using this in a cursors works fine:

```
declare C cursor for
select (select table_name, column_name, ordinal_position, data_type
        from information_schema.columns
        where table_name = ''
        order by 1,3
        for xml auto)
open C
declare @L varchar(max)
fetch next from C into @L
close C
deallocate C
select @L
```

Comment: if you wouldn't mind, could you help explain how this works. what does the 1,3 do with the order? and what exactly does the xml auto do? any links to useful tutorials maybe? thanks again - james :)

Comment: @James - 1,3 sorts the output on column 1 (table_name) and 3 (ordinal_position). `for xml auto` makes the entire result into a XML. Read more about it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173812.aspx. You can use `for xml path()` to get more control over how the xml is constructed.

Answer (score 2):

This should bring you all the information you require (tested on SQL Server 2005)

```
select table_name, column_name, ordinal_position, data_type
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = ''
order by 1,3
for xml auto
```

Comment: cheers @Jarede, but i'm not too sure how to explain this - i can't print out a list one expression with my limited access - all i can do is return one value at a time (hence the cockhanded way of previously listing the table names)

Comment: - the feild builder rejects only statement which returns more than one value, hence the mutliple selects and the TOP 1, 2, 3 method i previoulsy used to return the table names

Comment: @James – Just add `for xml auto` to the query and the result will be one row, one column with some XML data that you can parse on the client side.

Comment: @Mikael the feild builder gives me the following error `the FOR XML clause is not allowed in a CURSOR statement`