# chaning the view/style of sql xml auto

Tags: sql, xml, cursor

i have the below peice of code (following on for my earlier question [SQL How to list Columns in a Table as a Cursor Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881952/sql-how-to-list-columns-in-a-table-as-a-cursor-statement))

```
select 
    (select * from
        (select Narrative 
         from OfficeClientLedger
         where ptMatter=$Matter$ and ptTrans = 4) 
     as Disbursments for xml auto)
```

Which returns

```
<OFFICECLIENTLEDGER NARRATIVE="M0604/20 Cwm Taff NHS Trust Medical Records (C)"/><OFFICECLIENTLEDGER NARRATIVE="M0604/210 Dr Purby Medeical Records (C)"/><OFFICECLIENTLEDGER NARRATIVE="M0604.20 Orchid Cellmark tld Fee"/><OFFICECLIENTLEDGER NARRATIVE="M0604/20 Parsons Dowd Psychological Ltd Assessment Fees"/><OFFICECLIENTLEDGER NARRATIVE="M0604/20 Dr R  Oretti Drug testing"/><OFFICECLIENTLEDGER NARRATIVE="M0604/20 Correction of MIssposting CQ 013524"/><OFFICECLIENTLEDGER NARRATIVE="M0604/20 Helen Blackler Assessment Fees (P) "/>
```

However, I need it to bring me a list such as

> M0604/20 Cwm Taff NHS Trust Medical
>   Records (C)
>
> M0604/210 Dr Purby Medeical Records
>   (C)
>
> M0604.20 Orchid Cellmark tld Fee
>
> M0604/20 Parsons Dowd
>
> M0604/20 Dr R  Oretti Drug testing
>
> M0604/20 Correction of MIssposting CQ
>   013524
>
> M0604/20 Helen Blackler Assessment
>   Fees (P)

any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
(select cast(Narrative as varchar(max))
from OfficeClientLedger
where ptMatter=$Matter$ and ptTrans = 4
as Disbursments for xml path(''), true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an XSL style sheet to change the format of the XML retrieved from SQL Server.

http://sqlxml.org/faqs.aspx?faq=99